# How to minimize a JFrame window from Java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, minimize

In my Java app, I have a JFrame window, how can I minimize it from my Java program ?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

minimize with `frame.setState(Frame.ICONIFIED)`

restore with `frame.setState(Frame.NORMAL)`

Comment: @rogerdpack no, it works to show (visualize) hidden window, but not to restore from minimization

Answer (score 17):

Minimize:

```
frame.setState(Frame.ICONIFIED);
```

Another way to minimize:

```
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
```

Normal size:

```
frame.setState(Frame.NORMAL);
```

Another way to normal size:

```
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
```

Maximize:

```
frame.setState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Another way to maximize:

```
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Full Screen maximize:

```
GraphicsDevice device = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()[0];
try { device.setFullScreenWindow((java.awt.Window) frame); } catch (Exception e) { device.setFullScreenWindow(null); }
```

Refer to the [`JFrame` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) for more information.

Answer (score 12):

You can do this in two ways:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");

frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.ICONIFIED); // One way
frame.setState(JFrame.ICONIFIED); // Another way
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach

```
frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_ICONIFIED));
```

Comment: Didn't work. ICONIFIED did. Maybe i was firing the event to early, but the other one did work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:

```
this.setState(YourJFrame.ICONIFIED);
```

And you can use this code to maximize it:

```
this.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to code for a event of a component then try code below. And make sure the class which this code is included is extended by Frame class

```
private void closeMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt){                        
    this.setState(1);
}
```

Or create an instance of a Frame class and call setState(1);

Comment: `this.setState(1);` magic constants rules, why waste time writing `JFrame.ICONIFIED` when you can write `1` directly? :)

Comment: @kajacx Because other devs working on the project have no clue what `1` means; it's cryptic and harms readability, that's why

Comment: Besides, if they'd ever decide to change the value of the constants, your code would break for no apparent reason. Have fun debugging that