# JButton minimizing a window(JFrame)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Im trying to create my own Frame for my application.
I have removed the standard Frame by using `setUndecorated(true)`. I have a working exit button (not that difficult), but i want to have a JButton equal to the windows-minimizing-button in the top-right corner.
I have tried several solutions as `hide()`, `HIDE_ON_CLOSE` and even `setVisible()`. But non of them is giving me the wanted result.

Im extending a JFrame to my class.

I am thinking of some Mouselistener(?), but im like a big question mark right now.

[image]

Comment: frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

Comment: Doesn't work in my case, Im extending a JFrame in my class, and even if i remove frame and just write `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE)` it still gives me nothing

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965336/how-to-minimize-a-jframe-window-from-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.google.com/search?q=jframe+minimize

1st link:

http://java-puzzle.blogspot.com/2009/07/tutorial-to-minimize-jframe-dynamically.html

`frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);`

Comment: By setting extended state this way you are losing another states of a window. Using `frame.setState(JFrame.ICONIFIED)` for minimizing a window is more preferable according to the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setState(int)).