# How to minimize a JFrame by clicking on a JButton

Tags: java, swing, jframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JButton minimizing a window(JFrame)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737751/jbutton-minimizing-a-windowjframe)

I removed the JFrame's close/minimize buttons, and I want to add my own buttons, for close, it can work by using `.dispose();`, but what should I use to minimize the JFrame if I click on a JButton?

I think `.setVisible(false);` will hide it completely, and I won't have anything to click on,  in the TaskBar to get the JFrame back.

Comment: and another dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965336/how-to-minimize-a-jframe-window-from-java

Comment: Sorry for not searching!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `.setState(Frame.ICONIFIED)`

Working Example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class FrameTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        JButton button = new JButton("Minimize");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.setState(Frame.ICONIFIED);
            }
        });
        frame.add(button);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't works for un_decorated Top-Level Container

Comment: @mKorbel why not, see my edit

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
frame.setExtendedState(frame.getExtendedState | Frame.ICONIFIED);
```

or

```
frame.setExtendedState(frame.getExtendedState | ~Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```