# Window closing and single instance of JFrame

Tags: java, swing

Two + 1 Questions:

1. I've an stand alone application and created a runnable jar for it. Now, when I double-click it, a `JFrame` window opens and I need to log in. The problem is that I can open multiple JFrame windows if I double-click on it. What I need is once I have logged in, anytime I try to open it again, it should show me the currently logged in window. Or to put it this way, create a single instance of that `JFrame` window.
2. When closing the window, I need to do some operations before closing. I know that I can use  a `WindowListener` but this does not work when I shutdown the JFrame (as in terminate the application). Is there a way to do any action before terminating manually?

EDIT : Another question:

1. I did a `setExtendedState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);` for minimizing the `JFrame` window when 'x'(close) is clicked. It minimizes but vanishes from the task bar. Is there a way to keep in the task bar like how the normal minimize works?

Comment: for your 3rd question take a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965336/how-to-minimize-a-jframe-window-from-java) because iconified state makes an icon on the task bar C: also check [this other link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737751/jbutton-minimizing-a-windowjframe)

Comment: I do not see any icon when I click 'x'. It minimizes but vanishes from the task bar. The application will still be running.

Comment: have you tried clicking on the little arrow next to the clock? maybe there's where it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)

Have your main method search for another instance of the program. If one is found, focus that window and have it close itself. You can read more about that in a similar question here: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082265/how-to-ensure-only-one-instance-of-a-java-program-can-be-exucuted)

2)

Use a shutdown hook:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {

    @Override
    public void run() {...} //your code to run when closing the program

}
```

Comment: Thanks. That was what I was searching for! `ShutDownHook`. And thanks for the link. Will take a look!

Comment: For 1) it worked with the code given in the link. Worked when I said is that there is no new window that opens. But, how will I get the already opened window to come into focus. I can fetch the processid/processname but can I use this to do it?

Comment: Hm, Not entirely certain. I suppose you could be tricky with something like sockets, but that kind of cross-process communication starts to get tricky with Java.

Comment: Hmm I tried `addShutdownHook`, and when I try to terminate from eclipse, it does not run! Is there anything else to be done?

Comment: `kill -9` or forcible closure of the program won't run shutdown hooks, which I imagine eclipse's environment might do. You should try running it separate from the IDE