# Java - How to "unhide" a JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I am quite new to Java, but familiar with native Android dev so bear with me xD. I created an application that creates a JFrame. Then I set the closeOperation to: `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);`.

It performs as expected, the frame is hidden and this is what I want (when I close). I need the application to keep on running (only once instance), because I am running a thread in the background that is performing an operation.

My actionListener on my button in my JFrame currently does this: `setVisible(false);`

My question is this, how can I maximize the JFrame again after it has been hidden? Would it be possible to display the frame when the user clicks on the minimized application in the task bar? Is there some type of listener that I need to implement?

Thanks in advance, any advice will be appreciated

**UPDATE**

For this solution to work correctly you need to do the following. Also have a look at XtremeBaumer's answer for this to make sense.

On JFrame creation `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);`.
When you want to minimize the app (on click possibly) `frame.setState(Frame.ICONIFIED);`.
When you want to maximize the app again `frame.setState(Frame.NORMAL);` in `windowDeiconified` event.

One last thing, if you want to also minimize your app when the user clicks on the exit button (red x) add this to the `windowClosing` event `frame.setState(Frame.ICONIFIED);`.

Comment: By creating an instance of this JFrame, and then call the `setVisible(true)` method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    this.addWindowListener(new WindowListener(){

        @Override
        public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            setState(Frame.ICONIFIED)
        }

        @Override
        public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
            this.setVisible(true);
            //this should be what you want
        }

        @Override
        public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
        }

    });
```

i hope this solves your question. add it to your JFrame

Comment: Thank you, maybe also add this to your answer (worked when I implemented this answer) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965336/how-to-minimize-a-jframe-window-from-java . Otherwise the `windowDeiconified` event is never called

Comment: so i found the problem, that once you setVisible(false) or hide() the window, the user cannot show it again by clicking the icon, because there is no icon. how did you solve that?

Comment: When the JFrame is created, do this instead (I will edit to my question today). `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);`. Then you need to handle the closing of the JFrame on your own by using `frame.setState(Frame.ICONIFIED);` and `frame.setState(Frame.NORMAL);`. Iconified minimizes and normal reverts. User should not be able to close my app, yep dodgy, but with good reason. Clients orders.